# Converting from JSON using GSON, cannot cast ArrayList into object

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I'm trying to save my data using SharedPreferences by converting my ArrayList into JSON. Whenever I try to retrieve data and convert it back I get cannot cast ArrayList into Playlist error. Any ideas what's might be wrong here?

My Playlist class:

```
public class Playlist extends ArrayList<Parcelable> implements Parcelable{
private ArrayList<Song> playlistSongs;
private String name;

public Playlist(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.playlistSongs = new ArrayList<>();
}

protected Playlist(Parcel in) {
    playlistSongs = in.createTypedArrayList(Song.CREATOR);
    name = in.readString();
}

public static final Creator<Playlist> CREATOR = new Creator<Playlist>() {
    @Override
    public Playlist createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Playlist(in);
    }

    @Override
    public Playlist[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Playlist[size];
    }
};

public ArrayList<Song> getPlaylistSongs() {
    return playlistSongs;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return name;
}

public int getCount(){
    return playlistSongs.size();
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
    parcel.writeTypedList(playlistSongs);
    parcel.writeString(name);
}

@Override
public Stream<Parcelable> stream() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public Stream<Parcelable> parallelStream() {
    return null;
}
```

}

My convert to JSON method I call after creating all of the playlists in activity:

```
public boolean writeJSON(ArrayList<Playlist> playlists) {

    SharedPreferences mSettings = getSharedPreferences("Playlists", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = mSettings.edit();

    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Playlist>>() {
    }.getType();
    try {
        String writeValue = mGson.toJson(playlists, type);
        mEditor.putString("Playlists", writeValue);
        mEditor.commit();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And my read JSON method I call after user relaunch application:

```
    public ArrayList<Playlist> readJSON() {

    SharedPreferences mSettings = getSharedPreferences("Playlists", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Type collectionType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Playlist>>() {
    }.getType();
    String loadValue = mSettings.getString("Playlists", null);
    ArrayList<Playlist> temp = mGson.fromJson(loadValue, collectionType);
    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is that the `Playlist` class extends `ArrayList`. GSON is trying to serialize your `Playlist` as a list of `Parcelable`. Judging by your class, it doesn't look like `Playlist` truly needs to extend `ArrayList`. I tried running your example (I had to remove a lot in order to get down to the bare minimum) and it was serializing each `Playlist` as an empty list (the string `"[]"`), regardless of what was in `playlistSongs`. I removed the superclass and it started working as expected.

Comment: I haven't even noticed I extended my Playlist class. Thank you it's working!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is this `extends ArrayList<Parcelable>`. Try to make it `extends ArrayList<Song>` and also you do not need to hold a reference for the Arraylist (`private ArrayList<Song> playlistSongs;`)